# How to parse the cells of the 3rd column of a table?

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse the cells of the 3rd column of a `<table>` using Jsoup.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<b><table title="Avgångar:" class="tableMenuCell" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" id="GridViewForecasts" style="color:#333333;width:470px;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr class="darkblue_pane" style="color:White;font-weight:bold;">
        <th scope="col">Linje</th>
        <th scope="col">Destination</th>
        <th scope="col">Nästa tur (min)</th>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th scope="col">Därefter</th>
        <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="white_pane" style="color:#333333;">
        <td align="right" style="color:#000000;background-color:#01AEF0;">1</td>
        <td align="left">Hovshaga Kurortsv.</td><td align="right">55</td>
        <td align="left"></td>
        <td align="right">--</td>
        <td align="left"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="lightblue_pane" style="color:#284775;">
        <td align="right" style="color:#000000;background-color:#01AEF0;">1</td>
        <td align="left">Hovshaga via Resecentrum</td><td align="right">21</td>
        <td align="left"></td><td align="right">--</td>
        <td align="left"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="white_pane" style="color:#333333;">
        <td align="right" style="color:#000000;background-color:#01AEF0;">1</td>
        <td align="left">Teleborg</td><td align="right">5</td>
        <td align="left"></td><td align="right">45</td><td align="left"></td>
    </tr>
</table></b>
```

Here is my code attempt which throws a `NullPointerException`:

```
 URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL("http://wap.nastabuss.se/its4wap/QueryForm.aspx?hpl=Teleborg+C+(V%C3%A4xj%C3%B6)");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("1");
Document doc = null;
try {
    System.out.println("2");
    doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("3");
Element table = doc.select("table[title=Avgångar:]").first();
System.out.println("3");
Iterator<Element> it = table.select("td").iterator();

//we know the third td element is where we wanna start so we call .next twice
it.next();
it.next();
while(it.hasNext()){
  // do what ever you want with the td element here
System.out.println("::::::::::"+it.next());
  //iterate three times to get to the next td you want. checking after the first
  // one to make sure
  // we're not at the end of the table.
  it.next();
  if(!it.hasNext()){ 
    break;
  }
  it.next();
  it.next();
}
```

It goes till the second `System.Out.Println("3");` and then it stucks.

Comment: "It goes till the System.Out.Println("3");" Which one? You have two of those...

Comment: Every `it.next()` calls shouldn't be made without protective `if(it.hasNext)` tests. Unless it.next() throws an exception you can catch (and you catch it).

Comment: @Thilo: it goes till the last system.out.println("3").

Comment: Do I have to put some Regular Expression in this case or what should I do ??

Answer (score 4):

This approach is quite a mess and you didn't tell anything about at which line the NPE occurred, so it's hard to give a straight answer to your question.

Apart from that, I would suggest to not do it the hard and error prone way. As that `<table>` has already an `id` attribute which is supposed to be unique throughout the document, just use the ID selector `#someid`. Further, you can get the cells of the 3rd column using the index selector `:eq(index)` (note: it's zero based!).

So, those few of simple lines should do it:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://wap.nastabuss.se/its4wap/QueryForm.aspx?hpl=Teleborg+C+(V%C3%A4xj%C3%B6)").get();
Elements nextTurns = document.select("#GridViewForecasts td:eq(2)");

for (Element nextTurn : nextTurns) {
    System.out.println(nextTurn.text());
}
```

which results here in:

```
50
30
10
18
3
24
```

That's it.

I strongly recommend to invest some time in properly learning the CSS selector syntax as Jsoup is build around it.

#### See also:

- [Jsoup CSS selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)
- [Jsoup `Selector` API](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)
- [W3 CSS3 selector specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use `get();` method to get single `element` from number of `elements`.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("your_url").get();
Elements table = doc .getElementById("id_of_your_table");
Element tr = table.select("tr").get(2); // this will get 3rd tr
//if you need 3rd column of 3rd row then 
Element 3rdtd = tr.select("td").get(2);
Log.i("3rd Column of 3rd Row", 3rdtd.text().toString());
```

Hope it will help.