# Jsoup select command operation

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

I am new to Jsoup.

I am able to use select command

```
Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
```

if you see this : en.wikipedia.org/wiki/States_and_territories_of_India . In that I want to have all the Names in States of India only. But there are other tables also , when I do doc.select("area[title]"); I am getting all the table information . so I am looking if in select I can tell how it is used to only for a particular table.

I think Jsoup might not address this if that is the case,can you please tell me how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
Element indiaTable = doc.select("table").get(2); //India table is the third (index is 2) table on page
Elements myTds = indiaTable.select("td:eq(0)"); //The states are the first column

//or you can replace the two lines of code above with this

Elements myTds = doc.select("table.wikitable td:eq(0)");



for (Element td: myTds ) {
    System.out.println(td.text());
}
```

Comment: danial, Thank you. but it is giving syntex Error .Multiple markers at this line..insert } to complete the block in system.out.println().

Comment: Try refreshing the project folder and doing a build... take another look at your code, maybe some missing/extra bracket...

Comment: Daniel, I tried and I am not having any compile issues. But I dont see the table getting printed

Comment: take a look at this example , its similar to yours (and my answer) http://stackoverflow.com/q/7864433/617373

Comment: Thankq . what if there is no ID for the table.  I have posted that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979978/html-table-id-and-class-id/11980196#11980196 but did not get the reply

Comment: thats why i used .first()  - > `doc.select("table").first();` it should select the first table on page (which is the table you are looking for)

Comment: Thanks for reply. can you pl give me the complete snipp..I am really not getting how to get the first colum in that table..

Comment: that what i thought i gave you `Elements myTds = indiaTable.select("td:eq(0)");` ("td:eq(0)" should select the first column just like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7894011/617373 that selects the third column)

Comment: I tried that and it prints noting.  Element indiaTable = doc.select("table").first();
        Elements myTds = indiaTable.select("td:eq(0)");
        for (Element td: myTds ) {
            System.out.println(td.text());
        }   ==compiles, executes no errors but is not printing anything

Comment: Can you please give me a snipp that is working to get the states that are present in th efist coum

Comment: here it is ... `Element indiaTable = document.select("table").get(2); //India table is the third (index is 2) table on page` updated my answer

Comment: It works but in the same one how can I get the urls associated? when you do td:eq(0), it gives the first colum but how to get the href

Comment: here you go `System.out.println(td.text()+" , " + td.select("a").attr("href"));`