# HTML table id and class id

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

How can I find the Table id of the large table on in the following url: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/States_and_territories_of_India

I was able to see the classes `wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter`

This is the table which has list of states in India. I was able confirm from firebug that this table = `wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter` is having the list of states. How can I get the ID of that table?

What is the CSS equivalent to get all the names in that table?

I want to get only the states... the first column. I am using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: You can use “Inspect element” to see the properties of any HTML element. However, this table does not seem to have an ID. Not sure what you mean with that last question; CSS is not a query language.

Comment: I haven't found any elements with classes `wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter`, only `wikitable sortable`. Also, if a table has no ID, you would not be able to get the ID.

Comment: `wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter` is three different classes.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want a CSS selector capable styling the states in the table with `<caption><big>States of India</big></caption>`. Is that what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ID on that table. If you want to get the content of the table which has the class "wikitable". Use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) with this code

```
package com.main;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Document doc;
        try {

            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/States_and_territories_of_India").get();
            Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("table.wikitable").get(0).select("td:eq(0) a");

            System.out.println(newsHeadlines.html());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work I did not get the table. I want to get only the states..the first coum

Comment: In that case, you should update your question. Check out my new code

Answer (score 1):

If this is still pending issue, here is how you can get list of states in India :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/States_and_territories_of_India").get();

        Elements tables = doc.select("table");

        for (Element table : tables) {
            Element tableCaption = table.getElementsByTag("big").first();
            if (tableCaption != null && tableCaption.text().equals("States of India")) {
                Document statesDoc = Jsoup.parse(table.toString());
                Elements states = statesDoc.select("tr td:eq(0)");
                for (Element state : states) {
                    System.out.println(state.text().replaceAll("\\[\\d\\]", ""));
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're trying to screenscrape this table.

The answer to your question is there there is **no id** on that particular `<table>`.

The html that starts the table is:

```
<table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter" style="width:70%;">
```

As you can see there is no `id` attribute for that element.

What libraries are you using to parse the HTML? In JavaScript you could use `document.getElementsByClassName('wikitable')[0]` and find that uniquely on the page. But the syntax you would use will depend on what kind of HTML DOM traversing are available to you.

Comment: Yes you are right I am trying to do screenscrape. I am using JSOUP

Comment: But I an still having the issue

Comment: @TheLearner I updated your question to indicate what you're using and hoping to do.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` element is optional; not every element on a page will have one. This table doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery. You want the first table with classes wikitable sortable jquery-table-sorter.

```
$(".wikitable.sortable.jquery-table-sorter").first()
```

Although, the css classes could change at any time so I wouldn't rely on that. It might be worth asking someone who can edit the wiki page to add an id to all the tables.