# Android parse html table with JSoup

Tags: android, html, jsoup, html-table

I have looked around on stack overflow and I have found the following posts:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864433/how-to-parse-the-cells-of-the-3rd-column-of-a-tablehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864433/how-to-parse-the-cells-of-the-3rd-column-of-a-table

but I am still a bit confused.

What I have is a html table that contains a few of these inside the `<tbody>` tag with different dates:

```
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <nobr>Fri</nobr>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <nobr>Sep 20</nobr>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <nobr>4:00 PM</nobr>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Practice                </td>
            </tr>
```

The table's id is "*gymschedule*".

So far I can get the table with JSoup and I can display it in a webview with JSoup.

What I need is **to get the text of the second `<nobr>` in the second `<td>`, and also do this for every other group of `<tr>` tags in the table**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what the original source looks like completely, but this should work.

You can use CSS-selectors to select specific tags in your document, and specify what properties they should have, using ***pseudo selectors***.

If you would want to select only the `<tr>`-tags that are the first in a sequence of many, you would use the `tr:eq(0)` selector.

In your case you would end up with something like:

```
    doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
    Elements elements = doc.select("tr td:eq(1) nobr");
    for (Element e : elements) {
        System.out.println(e.text()); 
    }
```

which will print out

```
Sep 20
```

As I do not know how your complete source look like, you might be able to use the default HTML parser `Jsoup.parse(html);`, though that wont work on the snippet you have provided.

Examples of other pseudo selectors could be

```
:lt(0) //Less than
:gt(0) //Greater than
```

I suggest you read up on using selector-syntax.

[Use selector-syntax to find elements](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)