# Issue using Sibling Index in JSoup 1.8.2

Tags: java, jsoup

New to Java. Trying to learn/practice JSoup.

Goal: Extract the "Close" column from the Historical Prices off Yahoo Finance.

The code below returns both the "Close" prices and the "Adj Close" prices.

"S" below is any ticker in the SP 500.

Found another post which I've been using as a model. (here: [How to parse the cells of the 3rd column of a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864433/how-to-parse-the-cells-of-the-3rd-column-of-a-table)).

```
public class MovingAverage200 {

private String ticker;
private String movingAverageURL;
double movingAverage200;

public MovingAverage200(String s)   {

    ticker = s;
    movingAverageURL = ("https://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s="+ticker+"+Historical+Prices");

}

public void setMovingAverage()  {

    try {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(movingAverageURL).get();
        Elements prices = document.select("td.yfnc_tabledata1:eq(4)");

        for (Element price : prices) {
            System.out.println(price.text());
        }

    }
    catch (IOException ex)  {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is working correctly for me on Jsoup 1.8.3 on JVM

Comment: If you are using a previous release (1.8.2) then just use the latest. There were some performance tweaks that introduced bugs regarding siblings.

Comment: I am using 1.8.2. I'll update and post my results.

Comment: You were right. It works perfect now after switching to 1.8.3.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint posted by [alkis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1138559/alkis):

> If you are using a previous release (1.8.2) then just use the latest. There were some performance tweaks that introduced bugs regarding siblings.